# How can I drag all elements with same class to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XUygj/2/

I need to **drag all list items at once** with the class "active" upon click of any of these elements and allow them to be dropped on any of the drop container elements:

[image: multiple drag and drop]

If I click and hold any of the green items (2,4,5) in the screenshot above, I should be able to drag **all of them over at once** to any of the yellow containers and trigger a js function to handle the selected items appropriately.

How can I accomplish this?

I also need to retain the ability to drag-n-drop single, unselected list items (without the `active` class) one at a time.

I have a one-at-a-time [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XUygj/1/) that's working.  I just can't figure out multiple drag-n-drop.

HTML: ( http://jsfiddle.net/XUygj/2/ )

```
<ul class="drop-containers">
    <li class="drop1">Drop 1</li>
    <li class="drop2">Drop 2</li>
    <li class="drop3">Drop 3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="items">
    <li class="item1" data-object="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item2 active" data-object="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item3" data-object="item3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item4 active" data-object="item4">Item 4</li>
    <li class="item5 active" data-object="item5">Item 5</li>
    <li class="item6" data-object="item6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.items > li').draggable({ revert: "invalid" });

    $('.drop-containers li').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this); // reuse JQuery object.
            var droppedObject = ui.draggable.data('object'); // get object type
            ui.draggable.remove();
            $this.append(', ' + droppedObject);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.drop-containers {
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.drop-containers li {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    background:#ffc;
}

.items {
    width:120px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.items li {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    border:1px solid;
    margin:10px;
    background:#fff;
}
.items li.active {
    background:#dfc;
}
```

Comment: Have fun - [jquery-ui doppable + revert](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert)

Comment: That's fine.  I have single drag-and-drop working just fine — http://jsfiddle.net/XUygj/1/ .  But I'm missing how to drag and drop similar elements at the same time.  How can I grab all three active list items at once?  (2,4, and 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `helper` option in jQuery draggable, and when they drag you clone the three active elements as the helper. For instance:

```
$('.items > li').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: function(event) {
        var helperList = $('<ul class="draggable-helper" />');
        if ($(this).is('.active')){
            helperList.append($(this).siblings('.active').andSelf().clone());
        } else {
            helperList.append($(this).clone());
        }
        return helperList;
    }
});
```

That helper function will append them to a ".draggable-helper" list so you can style it appropriately, and of course you'll want to modify it to your own needs.

Comment: Wow!  This is great!  http://jsfiddle.net/XUygj/16/ (how did it get to 16 so fast!)  One last thing... can you help me figure out the objects or classes for the selected items on drop?  See the fiddle for how only one item is passed along to the dropped object.  I need all three.  Can you help me get across the finish line here?

Comment: Updated! I got it working! http://jsfiddle.net/XUygj/34/  Thanks so much for your help.